# Run Configuration for C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-cdt

I have just started to learn C++, but I can't get CDT to work with eclipse. I have installed MinGW and MSYS 1.0. When I tried to first run the Hello World tutorial program, I got an error along the lines of "no run program was specified." So, I tried to set up my run configuration, but I have no idea what to put under C/C++ application. To get to the run configuration menu I went to Run > Run Configurations. What should I put under C/C++ application to make this work? My code compiles fine, but I just can't run it.

Comment: Have you read this ? [Eclipse documentation ](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_o_run.htm?cp=11_3_5)

Comment: If you are just starting with C++, I would look into Visual Studio Express, or on Linux or OSX, a simple text editor + g++ and good tutorial. You are going spend more time messing around with Eclipse than learning C++.

Comment: Even though I gave my answer regarding Eclipse, I agree with Mike D. Vim/Emacs + GCC is certainly the way to go, if you really want to be literate and fluent C++ developer one day. However, I'm strongly against Visual Studio Express, and all that stuff offered by MS. I often stumble across people who don't know even how compilation/linking work because it was all hidden from them under bling-bling MS interfaces. To have strong knowledge of C++ infrastructure you should opt to GCC and a flexible text editor. This way you won't be so dependent on IDEs as thousands of average programmers are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been long time since I developed C++ in Eclipse. Of course I can write lots of instructions like what check box to click and what to write in which text field, but it wouldn't be fun, would it? Instead, I highly recommend that you first create a **Hello World** project by doing:

`File -> New -> C++ Project -> Executable -> Hello World C++ Project -> Next -> Next -> Finish`

Now build it. And try to run. You'll see that everything works fine. Now go to `Run -> Run Configurations...` and inspect how it was configured. Then simply do the same for your project. I believe that would be much better for you in a sense that you'll have some practice and will understand how Eclipse manages projects better.

If you have troubles of course I can expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I got my program to run, but do I need to do this for every project I make? Seems like somewhat of a pain compared to just hitting run no matter what when developing java in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, this is the most basic example of how C++ projects are built. First, you build your project, possibly in different configurations: like `debug` and `release`. And then you chose which one to run in order to check your results.

Comment: But, my comment along with Mike's still applies. It is fine to use Eclipse if you want to try C++ for a few weeks, learn a bit of syntax, and write simple programs. However, if you are aiming to improve steadilyб I strongly suggest that as soon as you feel that Eclipse restrains your flexibility somehow (and you will, trust me), then you should definitely start learning one of the modern build systems: such as [WAF](https://code.google.com/p/waf/), [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), [Scons](http://www.scons.org/), etc.

Comment: Then you would have to choose a flexible text editor like Vim/Emacs/Sublime and start tweaking it to your tastes: code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, code-refactoring, build automation, and tones of other stuff. That requires a huge time and effort investment. However, it is worth it, and believe me or not, when you are done - you would never return to IDEs be it Eclipse, Visual Studio, NetBeans, or whatever is there...

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I'll probably switch over to one of those "modern build systems" before I get used to Eclipse. Do you think it'd be a good idea to do the same for java?

Comment: Well, Eclipse was really made for Java development. The build systems which I listed are for C++ mainly. However, I think WAF can also handle Java too (bit I'm not sure). The key thing, why you should consider switching to flexible editors is that you get extremely productive with them. Because almost every single thing that could ever be customized to your taste is possible to customize with these editors with minimal effort. Additionally, a lot of people use these editors and create plugins for them, and what's more this is all free.

Comment: In contrast, Eclipse for example, is very heavyweight and is not that frequently updated - for example CDT plugin. So if there is a bug, you would probably have to tolerate it for months or maybe around a year. My point is, do not be dependent on such heavyweight giants who claim that they are a solution to all problems on the earth, because they are not and will never be. Instead build your own lightweight environment, which is always with you, anywhere where you have to develop.

Comment: Alright, I took your advice and started using Sublime Text. It all seems too easy though...all I do is type my code in, hit ctrl + b to build it, then ctrl + shift + b to run it. Am I doing something wrong? I don't see any difference between this and eclipse other than I can specifically customize stuff. (which I've found is actually really helpful, but is this the only advantage?)

Comment: The other advantage is that now you would have to look for a modern build system and learn it (See my comments above). This will allow you to easily create and maintain projects of any complexity with as many dependencies as you need. In addition, you'll have to be more familiar with how exactly compilation and linking is done. You'll have to learn more about toolchains (MinGW, GCC, Clang, MSVC, etc.) and their internals. This way you'll have much better knowledge of C++ infrastructure and can become very productive and proficient C++ developer.